# Drupal 8 Twig Entity Reference Sub Fields Templating

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8, templating

I'm trying to display sub fields of a multi value entity reference.

Tried:

```
    {% for item in node.field_related_items %}
            {{ item.content['#node'].field_author.value }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Also:

```
    {% for item in content.field_related_items %}
            {{ item.field_author }}
    {% endfor %}
```

If I do the following:

```
    {% for item in node.field_related_items %}
            {% set img1 = item.entity.field_featured_image %}
            {{ img1 }}
            {% set label1 = item.entity.label %}
            {{ label1 }}
    {% endfor %}
```

The label works, but not the image...

Same thing with:

```
item.entity.field_featured_image.value
```

No success,

Still not sure how to display sub fields of the entity reference...

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to image, taxonomy, links and plain fields templating:

```
    {% for item in node.field_related_items %}
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="img-wrap">{{ file_url(item.entity.field_featured_image.entity.uri.value) }} </div>

            {% set cat1 = item.entity.field_blog_category.entity.label %}
            <div class="cat-wrap">{{ cat1 }}</div>

            {% set label1 = item.entity.label %}
            <div class="title-wrap">{{ label1 }}</div>

            {% set aut1 = item.entity.field_author.value %}
            <div class="author-wrap">By <span>{{ aut1 }}</span> | 

            {% set date1 = item.entity.field_publish_date.value %}
            {{ date1 }}</div>

            <a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': item.entity.id}) }}">Link</a>

        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```